# How do I make http listener listen on a prefix without needing to type port in url bar?

Tags: c#, http

I was making a Http Server in CSharp, Code:

```
        listenWeb = new HttpListener();
        Server.listenWeb.Prefixes.Add("https://127.0.0.1:80/");
        listenWeb.Start();
```

I want to make the code above work without needing to type the url with port. How can I do that?

I tried to remove the `:80` from prefix but it didn't help at all.

Comment: What do you mean? Why do you type `:80` in your address bar? The default port for HTTP is 80, so including it is unnecessary.

Comment: Updated. Check.

Answer (score 1):

The default port for HTTP is 80. So `http://127.0.0.1:80` and `http://127.0.0.1/` mean exactly the same thing. The effect will be the same. In both cases, it will listen on port 80, and will only accept requests when accessed by the IP 127.0.0.1, which means it will only work from the local computer.

If you want it to accept requests from other computers, you use `http://*/`, which will make it accept requests from any IP and host name, on port 80.

You can read more about the format for prefixes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=netframework-4.8#remarks).